# Typescript param type refer to another param

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this

```
interface IObject {
   a: string;
   b: number;
   c: string[];
}
```

I want to build a function like this

```
function fancyName(obj: IObject, key: keyof IObject, value: any)
```

Currently you can put whatever you want into value. But I want to do something like this

- If `key` is `a`, then `value` type must be string
- If `key` is `b`, then `value` type must be number
- and so on

I have tried doing it like this `value: IObject[key]`, but it doesn't work. Cause I don't think it understands I try to refer to another param. How can I achieve this in TS?

Comment: Use generic types - if you have `T` (the object)` and `K` (a `keyof` it), then the parameter list is simply `obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jonrsharpe that bring the generic type to my mind. This is how I achieve it

```
function fancyName<K extends keyof T, T = IProduct>(object: T, key: K, value: T[K])
```